# What's the difference between en_GB and en_GB.UTF8 in PHP's setlocale()?

Tags: php

I have an issue with `setlocale()` in PHP when using functions such as `money_format()`.

In my localhost, such functions only work if my `setlocale()` value is `en_GB`. However, on my live server the same functions will only work if `setlocale()` is set to `en_GB.UTF8`.

So my question is: what causes the different requirements? As presently my configuration file has a dirty `if/else` statement to find what server it's being ran on and dynamically specifies the `setlocale()` value.

Comment: Locales are constants defined by the system. Use `locale -a` to see allowed settings. In a way they are magic values. And it's an arcane scheme with no established/dependable standard for aliases/fallbacks.

Comment: I ran `locale -a` in Terminal (my localhost is Mac) and found that Mac's name them with a hyphen in the `UTF8` bit for some reason, so the value I wanted was actually `en_GB.UTF-8`. I've had a look a PHP's documentation on `setlocale()` and have this in my script now: `<?php setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_GB_UTF8', 'en_GB.UTF-8'); ?>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what is the php version is there a diference ? diferent os ?

you can use this just change euro to what you need for money

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
setlocale(LC_ALL, array('en_GB.UTF8','en_GB@euro','en_GB','english'));
```